# how to get only todays posts based on expression match nodejs mongo moment.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

```
//this is my controller   
 async getTasksCount (req, res) {
        try {
            let resultall = {};
            const strDate = moment().startOf('day').utc().toDate();
            const endDate = moment().endOf('day').utc().toDate()
        
                let todayTask = await tasksRepo.getToDayTaskCount({"isDeleted" : false, "isScheduled": true, "isCompleted": false, startDate: { $ne: null }, 
                $expr: {
                    $or: [
                        { $gte: ['strDate', moment().startOf('day').utc().toDate()] },
                        { $lte: ['endDate', moment().endOf('day').utc().toDate()] }
                    ]
                }
                });
           
              console.log("x1"+strDate)
              console.log("x2"+endDate)
              console.log("xx"+ todayTask.length)
}


//this is the query written for expression match and to get projection of data with start and end date we have some kind of pattern we make repo called file in project in that we write queries or else normally this method would be in controller

    getToDayTaskCount: async (params) => {
        try {
            let aggregate = await TasksModel.aggregate([
               {
                   $project:{
                       _id: '$_id',
                       title: '$title',
                       description: '$description',
                       isCompleted: '$isCompleted',
                       isScheduled: '$isScheduled',
                       status: '$status',
                       strDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$start" } },
                       endDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$end" } },
                       isDeleted: '$isDeleted',
                    //    daysCount: {
                    //     $round: {
                    //       $divide: [
                    //         {
                    //           $subtract: [
                    //             "$end",
                    //             "$start"
                    //           ]
                    //         },
                    //         86400000
                    //       ]
                    //     }
                    //   }
                   },
               },
               {$match: params},
            ]);
           
            return aggregate;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    },
//this is my model if needed

    const TasksSchema = new Schema({
      title: { type: String, default: '' },
      workorder_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Workorders', default: null },
      manager: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', default: null },
      technicians: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', default: null }],
      description: { type: String, default: '' },
      start: { type: Date, default: null },
      end: { type: Date, default: null },
      timezone: { type: String, default: '' },
      isCompleted: { type: Boolean, default: false, enum: [true, false] },
      price: { type: Schema.Types.Double, default: 0.00 },
      status: { type: String, default: 'New', enum: status },
      isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false, enum: [true, false] },
    }, { timestamps: true, versionKey: false });
```

//some of background
I have to show total count of todays tasks using momentjs after getting the aggregated data I even got todays data but that was last years same date.  if i create 5 tasks today i must get 5 posts . so that i can take count of it and show it on dashboard I'm new to aggregation please help me out!

// what I have tried out of scope
I even tried mapping on results and filter it to get all taks and then count of only todays but in this way i got last years todays tasks as result that is not desired output

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making use of the `fromNow` function

> moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 17 hours ago

> moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 7 hours

> moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();

from `relative time` section

- https://momentjs.com/

Comment: but this is not quite im looking for  i have output something like this matching expression i have to bring only todays posts filtering it so                         [{
  {
    _id: 60f19ef6fc968a510aca6d28,
    title: 'ghdfh',
    description: '',
    isCompleted: true,
    status: 'Completed',
    startDate: '2021-07-23',
    endDate: '2021-07-23',
    isDeleted: false,
    daysCount: 0
  }

Comment: can u tell me how can i contact u no one is helping so